# How do I find out specific Coordinates for ImageViews to create Paths on another Pane

Tags: java, animation, javafx

The Problem is that every method i tried and found on the Internet returned me random coordinates that dont fit to the animation I want to do. What I am trying to do here is a method that creates a Path for an ImageView in my Animation Pane (Named imageBox). The FXML is pretty Complex and nested, so im trying to get the Coordinates of my ImageView I want to Animate from local to the whole Scene, and then back to the Animation Pane, to get the same coordinates. I dont know if thats the right way to do but I was pretty sure that this schould´ve worked out.
My Code for trying to create a simple Line Path is (these are Cards to move arround a Board, so i tried to get its center positon):

```
 private Path newLinePath ( ImageView imageView, Node startNode, Node targetNode) {
    Path path = new Path();
    playingCardsPane.getChildren().add(new ImageView());
    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(imageBox.sceneToLocal(startNode.localToScene(0,0)).getX() + imageView.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth()/2, imageBox.sceneToLocal(startNode.localToScene(0,0)).getY() + imageView.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight()/2));
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(imageBox.sceneToLocal(targetNode.localToScene(targetNode.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth()/2.,targetNode.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight()/2.)).getX(), imageBox.sceneToLocal(targetNode.localToScene(targetNode.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth()/2.,targetNode.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight()/2.)).getY()));

    return path;
}
```

And my Code for the Path Transition is:

```
public void pathTransition(ImageView imageView,Path path, int speed) {
    PathTransition animation= new PathTransition();

    imageBox.setDisable(false);
    imageBox.setVisible(true);
    animationImageView.setImage(imageView.getImage());
    standartImageViewFormat(animationImageView);

    animation.setDuration(Duration.millis(speed));
    animation.setPath(path);
    animation.setNode(animationImageView);
    animation.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
    animation.setCycleCount(1);
    //animation.setAutoReverse(true);
    animation.setOnFinished(e -> {
        imageBox.setDisable(true);
        imageBox.setVisible(false);
        mainGrid.setDisable(false);
        imageView.setVisible(true);
        animation.stop();
    });
    animation.play();
}
```

Picture from sceneBuilder, marked is my animationImageView:

[image: Picture from sceneBuilder, marked is my animationImageView]

Comment: [mcve] please (mind the __M__, that is __not__ your entire complex project, just an small example that demonstrates what you are after and how it doesn't do what you expect)

Comment: Ok sorry my fault you're definetely right. Was my first Post and I thought that maybw someone would know the problem at his first look.